# AWS Lambda scheduled with CodeStar: SyncResources com.amazon.coral.service.InternalFailure

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codestar

I'm trying to deploy scheduled AWS Lambda function using CodeStar. 
I have started from the webserver template of CodeStart and I have modified the template.yml in order to use the scheduled events.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
  - AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: app.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region','LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        MyEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
```

I had attached the Policie `CloudWatchEventsFullAccess` to the Role `CodeStarWorker-xxxxx-CloudFormation` in order to allow the `events:PutRule`.

When I launch the CodePipeline I end getting an error in the deploy stage (CloudFormation) saying:

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CodeStar::SyncResources    SyncResources1493352569577  com.amazon.coral.service.InternalFailure
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Not, I had created a pipeline without using CodeStar to launch the scheduled event

Answer (score 0):

No resources in your CloudFormation template are related to CodeStar so I think removing the 'AWS::CodeStar' line one the top should fix it.